# MongoDB Match $and doesn't work but $or does

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to match in a pipeline all documents between a given date range.

When using a `$or` I successfully get data that confirms the `$or` condition. However, switching it to `$and` I get no data back.

Match block:

```
{
    "fields.issueType.name" : "Bug",
        "fields.resolutionDate" : {
        "$exists" : false
    },
    $expr: {
        $and: [
            { $gte: ["fields.created", new Date("2020-01-01T00:00:00.0Z")] },
            { $lte: ["fields.created", new Date("2021-01-01T00:00:00.0Z")] }
        ]
    }
}
```

A sample of the document

```
"fields": {
   "created" : "2020-08-03T10:50:08.626+0100", 
}
```

I'm reading this in m head as get all documents where `fields.created` is greater than 2020-01-01 and less than 2021-01-01 so I would expect all documents created in 2020.

I'm using Mongo version 4.2.8

Have I got my reasoning wrong or is there a different way I should be doing this?

**Edit:**

The updated query now looks like:

```
db.getCollection("issues").aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$addFields" : { 
                "created_at_date" : { 
                    "$toDate" : "$fields.created"
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$match" : { 
                "fields.issueType.name" : "Bug", 
                "fields.resolutionDate" : { 
                    "$exists" : false
                }, 
                "$expr" : { 
                    "$and" : [
                        { 
                            "$gt" : [
                                "created_at_date", 
                                ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000")
                            ]
                        }, 
                        { 
                            "$lt" : [
                                "created_at_date", 
                                ISODate("2021-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000")
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }, 
    ]
```

Comment: What is the data type of `"fields.created"`? Please share a sample document showing the field.

Comment: You have a string type date data. You cannot possibly compare string with a date object. You can use `$toDate` aggregation operator to convert string to date type (and then compare).

Comment: You're right, I've converted the value to date however I still get back an empty array of documents

Comment: What about the other conditions - do they match?

Comment: Yeah they do, removing the entire `$expr` and the query works as expected

Comment: Can you post the $match stage, all of it.

Comment: Updated the question with the query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219537/discussion-between-prasad-and-chris-turner).

Answer (score 0):

Actually your `$and` is working. The real issue is that it can't find any documents which would be both greater than or equal to `new Date("2020-01-01T00:00:00.0Z")` and less than or equal to `new Date("2020-01-01T00:00:00.0Z")` That's why It would always return an empty list of documents.

Use `$gt` and `$lt` instead of `$gte` and `$lte`, respectively